# Bind a material Select control to an enum flag

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

How can I bind a `<mat-select multiple ...>` to an enum flag?

My TypeScript enum flag is defined like this:

```
export enum CarType {
  Sedan = 1 << 0,  // 001
  Coupe = 1 << 1,  // 010
  Jeep = 1 << 2    // 100
}
```

Then I have a property named *desiredCarType* containing all the different car types a person want to look for. E.g one might be looking for a *sedan* or *jeep*:

```
public desiredCarTypes: CarType = CarType.Sedan | CarType.Jeep;
```

I now want to bind my select box to the property *desiredCarType*.

Please see my Plunker for an initial attempt: http://embed.plnkr.co/i4ALFU/ . I assume I cannot bind directly but somehow must split the property into an array and then back.